# Nexus Suggested Repositories

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I setup an internal Nexus Maven repo and I had a question about which additional Maven repos I should include from the initial setup.  What are some suggested Maven repos?  So far I have added JBoss, Apache Releases, and Codehaus Releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know , all of these repos are synced with Central. You can verify this by looking up Apache or JBoss artifacts using [the maven central search engine](http://search.maven.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know other repos are synced with Central.  For JBoss, not all of their projects are sync.   Below is JBoss's wiki link describing it.  http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenRepositoryCentralSynchronization

Comment: Then it depends on whether you need other repos. For me, Central is usually enough.